# Role choosing algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am writing an algorith for matchmaking system in multiplayer game, but currently have no ideas about how to assign roles in group, except brute force approach (with some minor optimisations).

Here is the task:

1. we have a group of 1 to 6 players
2. each player can choose role *Tank*(T), *DamageDealer*(DD) or *Healer*(H) or **any combination of these roles**. I.e. paladin_of_light can heal allies (be the *Healer*) or deal damage to enemies (be *DamageDealer*), but not in the same time
3. each group requires 1 *Tank*, 1 *Healer* and 4 *DamageDealers*. If there are less than 6 players, then group can be any subset of required combination (i.e. group of 3 players can has 3 *DamageDealers* and this is perfectly fine)
4. algorithm must assign **one** role to each player or declare that this is impossible with such group

Comment: I too would pick brute-force, although guided brute-force, I would first pick the tank, in a way that I would first look if the "best class for tanking is here and has chosen tank as a role", then try that, and then gradually go down the list of "ok, since that didn't work out, what else can we try". By "try that", the code would then call into the "pick a healer" method, which after having found a potential healer would call into a "now assign damage dealers" method. But since I'm pretty sure this sounds like some kind of scheduling algorithm, I'm pretty sure someone has a better answer.

Comment: For such a small problem I would expect brute force to work quickly enough - for larger sizes I recommend you formulate it as a network flow problem and solve with a max flow algorithm.  You may also be interested in the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) if you have preferences for assignment.

Comment: Yeah, the brute-force solution sounds reasonable with this amount of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). It finds the most optimal match considering the preference of each player. So everyone should be satisfied with the result.

The wiki-page includes some pseudo-code for an algorithm

Comment: As far as I understand, Stable Marriage Problem assumes that there are equal set of roles and avatars, that in some cases of this task is not correct :(

Comment: You could add dummy players, with no specific preference for a role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) to figure out the best combination more efficiently than with using of brute-force.

To do this you have to choose a fitness function. In the first case with 6 players it is obvious - it is distance to the required combination of 1T 1H and 3DD. For other groups you should define a “perfect” combination or other criteria for fitness function.